# Save a password on a .txt file, to replace it later, if already exists

Tags: python

I need to save a password to a .txt file and run the program. If the password already exists for that user, I will ask if we want to replace it

```
import string
def registo():
    found = False
    with open("Accounts.txt", "r+") as file:
        for line in file:
            user, pw = line.split(":")
            if number == user:
                print("User already exists")
                found = True
    file.close()
    while found == True:
        changepw = input("Change user password?[s/n]")
        if changepw == "s":
            newpw = input("Insert new password")
            s = open("Accounts.txt").read()
            s = s.replace(number,'%s:%s\n'%(number,newpw))
            f = open("Accounts.txt", "w")
            f.write(s)
            f.close()


    if not found:
        with open("Accounts.txt", "a+") as file:
            account = '%s:%s\n'%(numeroaluno,password)
            file.write(account)
            print ('Saved!')

number = input("Insert username")
password = input("Insert password")
registo()
```

I expect the output of a line and password replaced, e.g. username:password

I'm getting this output on the .txt file:

```
8180324:flavio #The actually user
:pedroooo #When i try to replace the password of the first user
81803123:pedrooooo #Another user
```

But I want to replace the line, not add another one...

Comment: @TrebledJ The code works, but not the way I want it to ...

Comment: Hey there, welcome to SO! Could you show us an example of your file? Also, please translate the messages (such as `prints` and `inputs`) in your code to english. As a portuguese speaker I could easily understand it, but I'm afraid it wouldn't be that easy to someone not familiar with the language ;)

Comment: @mfx28 That's quite vague. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the *desired behavior*, a specific problem or error *in the question itself*. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: @HelenaMartins Thank you for the tips, already made it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were some issues with your code and I tried to fix it quickly. I think what you want is something like the following (but of course you should never save passwords as plain text to begin with).

```
import fileinput            
import string

def registo(username, password):
    found = False
    with open("Accounts.txt", "r+") as file:
        for line in file:
            user, pw = line.split(":")
            if username == user:
                print("User already exists")
                found = True
    file.close()
    if found == True:
        changepw = input("Change user password?[s/n]")
        if changepw == "s":
            output = ""
            for line in fileinput.input(["Accounts.txt"], inplace=True):
                if line.strip().startswith(username):
                    line = username+":"+newpw
                output = output + line
            f = open("Accounts.txt", "w")
            f.write(output)
            f.close()

    if not found:
        with open("Accounts.txt", "a+") as file:
            account = '%s:%s\n'%(username,newpw)
            file.write(account)
            print ('Conta Guardada')

username = input("Insert username")
newpw = input("Insert password")
registo(username, newpw)
```

Comment: Well, the replace actually worked, but now I cant only add one user, I'm getting this error:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\pedro\Desktop\steste\teste.py", line 35, in <module>
    registo(username, newpw)
      File "C:\Users\pedro\Desktop\steste\teste.py", line 28, in registo
    account = '%s:%s\n'%(username,newpw)
    UnboundLocalError: local variable 'newpw' referenced before assignment